# TF-Ranking transform data to ELWC - ExampleListWithContext

Tags: tensorflow, ranking

I have read all the guides, videos, and everything, but I have no idea how to convert my feature set to an ELWC datasheet format for TF-Rank ListWise problem. There is no description of this structure.

For example, a students profile is:

```
Student ID  age  grade  math%   physics%   english%  art%  math_competit  language_competit Rank
  14588     16    k12     98      67         88      100   first_place        very_good       5
```

If I have 20 students in the same class, how can I transform this data to be able to make a listwise prediction for every grade ( theoretically in every grade has 3 class with 20 students)

Comment: Hey Gábor, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I see there is an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62004669/tf-ranking-transform-data-to-elwc-examplelistwithcontext-form